# Should these VMware questions be re-closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, vote-to-close

This is a follow-up to [Kulfy](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy)'s question [Can these VMWares be un-merged?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18848/can-these-vmwares-be-un-merged)

The requested unmerge was done, and questions closed against the former merge target were reopened. Attempts were made to close them against the unmerged question, but since some of the active reviewers were not able to vote on them, the votes aged away. Then another attempt was made to re-close them which also failed, and the questions remain open:

- [Installing VMware player: "chmod: cannot access... no such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357307/installing-vmware-player-chmod-cannot-access-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [How can I install VMWare Player on Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366283/how-can-i-install-vmware-player-on-ubuntu-12-10)
- [How can I install VMware on Ubuntu 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371359/how-can-i-install-vmware-on-ubuntu-13-10)
- [How do I install VMware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459817/how-do-i-install-vmware)
- [How do I install VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1160479)

This may well signify that the community thinks these questions should not be closed, as [suggested in chat by Eliah Kagan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52804972#52804972), but there is only negative evidence for this conclusion since, on examining the review tasks in the questions' timelines, I found only one of all 10 tasks had any reviews (and that one showing only one reviewer, who voted to close). So perhaps people did not see the questions.

Or, if people saw the questions and felt that they should not be closed, maybe they felt that something was lacking from the target question's answers?

Should these questions be re-closed as duplicates of the newly unmerged target? Does the target question need improvement? Should anything else be done?

Comment: i think they should be closed as duplicates and the target is fine to close them against. I see no arguments against this on any of the posts, so sent them to review again, it might just be bad luck that they slipped through?

Comment: (*[VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware)*, not *VMWare*.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen I've fixed it :)

Comment: Strange - two days later and still very few votes on these Q.

Comment: @guntbert I myself, and several others who read meta and do moderation stuff, are unable to vote, either because of our involvement in originally closing or reopening the questions, or because we cast a previous close vote (that aged away) too recently.